# Receive multipart/form-data in java

Tags: java, json, multipartform-data

I am new to REST and need some help in extracting all parameters for a request the following format like parameter with tag  and :

```
Content-Type:  multipart/form-data; boundary=event-boundary

--event-boundary
Content-Type: application/json
{
     "name": "AAAAA",
     "DOB": "BBBBB",
     "age": "CCCCC",
}
--event-boundary
Content-Type: application/json
{
    "event": "DDDDD",
    "eventtype": "EEEEEE",
    "appid": "FFFFF",
    "tags": [
      "GGGGG"
    ],
    "TTTTTT": [
      "HHHHH"
    ],
    "ZZZZZ": [],
    "YYYYY": {
      "XXXXX": "IIIII",
      "RRRRR": "JJJJJ",
},
    "timeOfEvent": "2016-02-27 16:37:50.516"
  }
}
--event-boundary--
```

Comment: What kind of software stack are you using on the receiving end? Servlet-API based?

Comment: Hi Thilo, yes as per below imports

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: how could I receive such post, I tried request.get parameter but a null pointer exception occured